# How to read a line with a specific beginning

Tags: java, regex, string

I've a mail-content like this:

```
By: example@abc.com (could also be a username)
Subject: Test 
Message: This is a test message
```

Then I convert this [javax.Message](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Message.html) into a String with `(String) getContent()`.

Now I need to parse out the *By:* part. In the example, I need to get *example@abc.com*. But I can't use a Regex to search for an email, because the *By:* part could also be a username... So I need to search where *By:* is and the read the whole follwing text. But I don't know how I can do this.

So how am I able to read the *By:* content?

Comment: I updated my regex demo to include only usernames as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by this way you can get it without using regex -

- Find the begin index of required String
- Find the end index of required string.
- Substring your actual string using begin and end index.

...

```
int begIndex = yourString.indexOf("By:")+3;
int endIndex = yourString.indexOf("Subject:");
yourString.substring(benIndex,endIndex);
```

Now you can trim the result string to get the desired string value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be +4 since there is also a space

Comment: there may be some space at the end also. So personally i prefer trim operation which discard all the spaces

Comment: This version looks very simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

`(?<=By: )((\w+)(@(\w+)\.(\w+))?)`

This uses positive lookbehind and matches the second group only if it is preceeded by `'By: '`
Also works for usernames only.

Here is a demo:

http://regex101.com/r/rM1lR8

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you both for the regex solution. But becuase I understand the non-regex answer better, it will be the accepted answer. but +1!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example. It will parse all the text after the `By` until the newline(assuming `By` will not be at the last line).

```
String mailText = ".....";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=[\n\r]|^)By:[ ]+(.*?)[\n\r]"); // assume By will not be at the last line
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(mailText);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Using a positive lookbehind `(?<=[\n\r]|^)` the regex is checking whether the `By` at the beginning of the string, or after a new line character.